# Smack: Null returned for XMPPException.getXMPPError() and XMPPException.getStreamError() with wrong login username/password

Tags: authentication, xmpp, smack, sasl

I've searched everywhere, but I could not find an answer: when I try to log in on any XMPP server (my Openfire setup, talk.google.com, jabber.org) with invalid login username/password, the thrown XMPPException (message: SASL authentication PLAIN failed: not-authorized) does  not contain any XMPPError or StreamError (both are null).

The most curious thing is that the Spark Java XMPP client, that uses the same Smack version - v3.2.2 - as I do (I even swapped mine with the Spark one) can handle the invalid login credentials using getXMPPError, which returns the actual XMPP error object, not null! How is that even possible?

I went through the Spark source and I could not figure out anything. I tried countless variations - various ConnectionConfiguration settings, connecting to other Jabber/XMPP servers, nothing helped. I even sniffed the server responses with Wireshark, they are the same for Spark and my application.

I ended up parsing the damn return string "SASL authentication PLAIN failed: not-authorized"...

Can anybody shed some light here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but try something like

```
try {
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPCOnnection....
    connection.connect();
    .
    .
    .
} catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
}
```

The reason is that maybe you are looking for the wrong exception, by catching Throwable you will be looking for pretty much everything, so this code will not solve your problems but may put you on track, or provide you with some hints at least.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPException.html) on Ignite Realtime :

getXMPPError() 
Returns the XMPPError asscociated with this exception, or null if there isn't one.

I'm not certain but perhaps spark does in fact parse the error string like you do?